# Want to Add @JsonIgnore property on Password in response Json

Tags: java, spring, jersey, jackson

I want to add @JsonIgnore of Jackson On the Password property of User domain such that I must be able to send the Json With password and It saves my data in Database but in response I don't want to show the password.

How can I acheive this please help me.

I tried to use it at the Domain level of the User where the properties are defined but it Totally Ignore the property in the getter and setter methods.

I have tried this

```
private String password;
 @JsonIgnore
        public String getPassword() {
            return this.password;
        }
```

Comment: As a side note, you should NEVER do this. It's waaaaaay too easy for someone to come along and mess it up. Don't make it so easy. It would be catastrophic if this broke in production.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try using both [`@JsonIgnore`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) and [`@JsonProperty`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) in your class like this:

```
private String password;

@JsonIgnore
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

@JsonProperty
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49469715/jsonproperty-jsonignore-not-working-as-expected-on-write-only-property)). Any idea why the field is `null` after de-serialization?

Comment: It's also helpful using Lombok

Comment: @TOUDIdel In my opinion Lombok just add and extra dependency.

Answer (score 12):

You can do it this way too if you don't want to manually create the getters/setters (eg. 
 when using lombok's @Data)

```
@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private String password;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [DTO Pattern](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/transferobject-139757.html) to set / change password.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped to do it like that:

```
@JsonProperty
private String password;

@JsonIgnore
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **access property of @JsonProperty** as below.
This will avoid deserialization but since write access is provided, the password can be saved.

```
@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    @Column(name = "encrypted_password")
    private String password;
```

Access setting that means that the property may only be written (set)as part of deserialization (using "setter" method, or assigning to Field, or passed as Creator argument)but will not be read (get) for serialization, that is, the value of the property is not included in serialization.