# @JsonProperty/@JsonIgnore not working as expected on write-only property

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219037/want-to-add-jsonignore-property-on-password-in-response-json) I've tried to use `@JsonIgnore` and `@JsonProperty` (from `import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;`) on the `password` and `passwordSalt` fields of my `AppUser`.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_user")
public class AppUser extends AbstractTimestampEntity {

    // ..

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getPasswordSalt() {
        return passwordSalt;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public void setPasswordSalt(String passwordSalt) {
        this.passwordSalt = passwordSalt;
    }

}
```

However, for some reason the two fields are always `null`. As I try to "register" a user, the JSON I am sending is not getting de-serialized completely. `password` is set to `null`:

[image]

What I want to achieve is to be able to receive the user's password in order to store it, but at the same time make sure that the stored (encrypted) password is not being serialized and sent back to the client as well.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: do other string fields get populated? can you show the json being sent to deserialize?

Comment: @DanielM Well, at this point I am only working with Java objects. I am using Springs `TestRestTemplate` in order to serialize Java objects and send it to the server. The password is definitely being set. But so far I was not able to avoid sending back the (encrpyted) password to the client.

Comment: You are serializing an object on a test with what serializer? if it is this one then you won't have password serialized - and then it wouldn't be sent to server so it wouldn't be deserialized.

Comment: @DanielM I am not sure if I understand. My goal is to allow a client to send a password. That means if a client sends a json `{"password": "mypassword"}` the corresponding POJO should have the property `password` set to `mypassword`. On the other hand, if I fetch the entity from my database and send it to back to the client, I want this field to be ignored. It has to remain `null`. I am using Spring Boot here btw.

Comment: You are serializing a POJO with the field password, if you are using the same class (that has `@JsonIgnore` on `getPassword()`) - then it won't be serialized to json and sent to the server. So the server won't get a password field in the json and will set it to null

Comment: @DanielM But am I not doing it as you're suggesting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32219072/826983)?

Comment: Basically you have a problem with your test. Your test does not serialize the password field and therefore it is not sent to the server and then isn't being deserialized

Comment: Best is to check manually if it works with a json. If it does - then the problem is in your test, and most likely what I mentioned

Comment: @DanielM Hm, but as I remove those annoations the password does get sent correctly. I don't think that just because this runs in the environment of my unit tests would have anything to do with the way the data gets serialized. After all, the information how to treat the object is given in `AppUser`.

Comment: It's very important to not speculate by annotation.

Comment: May I ask which Jackson version you are using?

Comment: @StefanFalk
I am also facing the same problem, did you get a solution for it yet ?

Comment: @PushpendraPal Not yet. Haven't decided on how I'm going to do it but there's `@Projects` - you might want to take a look at it ([see here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.projections)).

Answer (score 2):

With Jackson version 2.9.0 the following works for me:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Credentials {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

…and a running test example…

```
@Test
public void jsonIgnoreSerialization() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    String serialized = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Credentials("user", "pass"));
    assertThat(serialized).isEqualTo("{\"username\":\"user\"}");

    Credentials credentials = objectMapper.readValue("{\"username\":\"user\",\"password\":\"pass\"}", Credentials.class);
    assertThat(credentials.getUsername()).isEqualTo("user");
    assertThat(credentials.getPassword()).isEqualTo("pass");
}
```

For the sake of simplicity the constructors are the ones from [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) and the assertions come from [AssertJ](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/).

Can you give this a try?

Comment: Strangely, `@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)` works for me, while `@JsonIgnore` does *not work*... Do you know why? Thanks!

Comment: so wierd, does work for me as well. thanks for the tip !