# FetchType.LAZY not working for @OneToOne relation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, one-to-one

I'm using JPA2 and Springboot2X. Trying to define a simple one-to-one relationship in `User` and `Account` tables.
`User` is the parent while `Account` is the child. The relationship is from parent to child. Followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214973/which-way-should-a-foreign-key-go-in-a-one-to-one-relationship).

`User` table has a column `account_no` to hold the account number which is the primary key of the `Account` table. So `User` holds the foreign key.

```
@Entity
public class Account extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable{

    // fields like account#, balance etc goes here..

    @OneToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;

}

@Entity
public class User extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable{

    // Other fields related to user entity go here ..

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_no", referencedColumnName = "account_number")
    private Account account;
}
```

Saving is working properly. But when I fetch a user ( `User user =  userRp.findByUserID(userid);`), I get data from both tables. My question is when I define `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` why the account table data is fetching? I only want the user data to be in the output as when I run the select query in the `User` table.

Output :

```
    {
    "id": 1,
    "userID": "xxxxx",
    "firstName": "Dsd",
    "llastName": "cccc",
    "email": "danqsaa@brown",
    "creation_date": "2021-12-19 19:41",
    "modified_date": "2021-12-19 19:41",
    "account": {
        "id": 2,           
        "accountNo": 6848982326,
        "balance": 4000.0,
        "creationUser": "xxx",
        "creation_date": "2021-12-19 19:41",
        "modified_date": "2021-12-19 19:41",
        "transactions": []
    }
}
```

DB output
[image]

### [image]

Added below RestController, Service, and Repo details.

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/users/{userID}")
        public ResponseEntity<Object> getUser(@PathVariable("userID") String userID){
                   return new ResponseEntity<>(userServiceImpl.getUserByID(userID), HttpStatus.OK)); 
        }
}

@Service
public class UserService {

 // injected user repo
public User getUserByID(String userID){
        return  userRepo.findByUserID(userID);      
    }
}

public interface UsersRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {
     User findByUserID(String userID);
}
```

Comment: your `Output` there - how are you serializing the data into that object? or is that just a json return from your select statement.

Comment: @cjnash   It's the output from my rest controller. from postman.

Comment: Just a thought here, maybe when the object is getting serialized, the getter() is being called, thus triggering the load. You could check this by debugging and checking what the query returns vs what you are returning via rest.
I could be wrong though.

Comment: Don't get your question - what did you expect? Jackson will access the property and this causes the association to load. Did you expect something else? What exactly? Also, where are your `@Transactional`?

Answer (score 1):

I thought I had the answer about this question, thinking it was just Jackson calling the getter during serialization for response object and that had as a result the fetch of the lazy property but it seems that this is not the case!!

This question was a good reason to dig and learn something strange from documentation.

The most common ORM vendor is hibernate. So if you read the documentation on hibernate it clearly states that **EAGER type is a must conform** for Hibernate, **but the LAZY fetch type is just a hint that hibernate may or may not follow** **!!**

From the [hibernate doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-column-annotation)

> fetch - FetchType
>
> (defaults to EAGER) Defines whether this attribute
> should be fetched eagerly or lazily. **JPA says that EAGER is a
> requirement to the provider (Hibernate) that the value should be
> fetched when the owner is fetched, while LAZY is merely a hint that
> the value is fetched when the attribute is accessed**. **Hibernate ignores
> this setting for basic types unless you are using bytecode
> enhancement**. See the Bytecode Enhancement for additional information
> on fetching and on bytecode enhancement.

Also according to the doc,  you have to follow at least for now the bytecode enhancment in order for lazy loading to work

> As a hopefully temporary legacy hold-over, it is currently required
> that all lazy singular associations (many-to-one and one-to-one) also
> include **@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)**. The plan is to relax
> that requirement later.

Also according to [hibernate performance enhancement doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#BytecodeEnhancement-enhancement) you also need a configuration property for hibernate, so in a Spring Boot App, please also include the following in your application.yml or properties file.

```
hibernate.enhancer.enableLazyInitialization = true
```

After you include this property, your entity must be updated to

```
@Entity
public class User extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable{

    // Other fields related to user entity go here ..

    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)  <------
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_no", referencedColumnName = "account_number")
    private Account account;
}

@Entity
public class Account extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable{

    // fields like account#, balance etc goes here..

    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY) <-----
    @OneToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;

}
```

All these are needed just for hibernate to enable the lazy loading functionality.

Then you would still see it in your response, because Jackson would call the getter method while serializing so it will force hibernate to fetch the value. So you also need to inform jackson to not use this getter during serialization.

So you must also update

```
  @Entity
  public class User extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable{

    @JsonIgnore <--------
    @JsonProperty(access =  JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY) <-------
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY) 
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_no", referencedColumnName = "account_number")
    private Account account;
```

Hopefully after all this should you be able to not see the account response because of lazy loading.

Comment: This is not working. I'm still getting the Account object in postman

Comment: @everalian What is your controller? Please update the question with the relevant code

Comment: Updated remaining code. Thanks.

Comment: @everalian please check updated answer

Comment: Not sure your answer works. however, when I use 
`@JsonProperty(access =  JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)` only, it works. as in this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49469715/jsonproperty-jsonignore-not-working-as-expected-on-write-only-property

Comment: @ever alian Yes it works because jackson will not use the getter to writte it in the output. But the value would be probably picked by database as with only the JsonProperty it will not be a lazy field. You can verify by using property `hibernate.show_sql=true` and checling the sql executed

Comment: That solution also not working. weird!. In the sql, I saw it's calling 2 select sqls. One is for the User and another one is for Account but with left outer join users. But the record fills null values to the User data. Eg. (Select accountX.field1, accountX.field2, userY_.l_name  from account accountX_ left outer join users userY_ on accountX_.id=userY_.account_no where accountX_.cust_account_number=5924460807)

Comment: @everalian wait please don't mix everything up as I think you have messed up many things here. The query you provided seems like you are searching something by accountId. So this must be the account controler you invoke and not the UserController that we talk about in this question.

Comment: no. it is the same query. I am trying to get the user details by user id. So, it fetches the account details also. this is the initial question. Why it is fetching account details where I don't want to show them or fetch them. I gave you there the second query that was executing.

Comment: @everalian please update the question and post exactly the queries executed in DB for user controller so we can understand

Answer (score 0):

It's unfortunate that the question is misleading and it takes many comments to find out what you're asking. Finally I understand - you see the field in JSON and you don't want to. This is a purely Jackson-related question and Hibernate has nothing to do with it.

There are several ways you can take:

#### Use DTO

There's a good reason we don't use our Entities as part of JSON serialization - exactly because it's rare that they satisfy our JSON requirements.

So instead we create a special DTO class which maps exactly how we need it for a particular endpoint. We convert our Entity to the DTO (and it will not include `account` field) and then serialize DTO.

#### Using Jackson Views

Jackson has a notion of a [JsonView](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView.html) - it lets you map the same object differently depending on the view that you request. This way you can make `account` field invisible to that particular endpoint.

#### Ignore properties

As was already hinted in the other response - you can `@JsonIgnore` the property or rid of its visibility or making it deserialize-only with WRITE_ONLY.

#### Jackson Hibernate module

Jackson has "plugins" specific for Hibernate: [jackson-datatype-hibernate](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate). They allow to be configured to ignore lazy fields and not initialize them. In such case Jackson will serialize null ([HibernateXModule.Feature](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-datatype-hibernate/javadoc/h5/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/hibernate5/Hibernate5Module.Feature.html)).

This is probably the worst option of all because you really don't want to tie how you optimize your work with DB and your presentation layer.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you suggesting here?

Comment: I'm trying to explain that the bahviour that you see is expected. From the question it's not clear why you thought it wasn't expected.

Comment: are you trying to say this is normal behavior? Fine, then how to avoid fetching the child data? The only working way is adding the `@JsonProperty(access =  JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)`. But that doesn't stop calling a second select query with leftouter join to the User table. This means, hibernate call is still happening to fetch account detaisl, but only not showing in the rest response.

Comment: Now it's clear what you need. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for update. The question has mentioned my problem with the json output. I wasn't sure where is the porblem when I post it. However, with the help of all of you, I found that Jackson cause the initialization.

Comment: @everalian If there was no solution provided as an answer for your problem but you found out another solution different please share it as your own answer to help future developers facing the same issue.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev `Finally I understand - you see the field in JSON and you don't want to. This is a purely Jackson-related question and Hibernate has nothing to do with it.` OP clearly stated that he wanted lazy loading to be functioning which was not. It was partly observed by response which related with jackson, but that was not the complete problem the OP had.